# Using hooks for a simple fetch request and breaking the rules of hooks, unsure how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple fetch with hooks from an AWS database. At the moment it errors out and the only reason I can see is because it breaks the rules of hooks but I'm not sure how. It's at the top level of this functional component and it's not called inside an event handler.

The result of this call (an array of user data), needs to be exported as a function and called in another file.

If anyone can spot something I have missed and can highlighted how I'm breaking the rules of hooks I'd be grateful!

Thanks!

```
const FetchUsers = () => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [Users, setUsers] = useState({});

  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "USERSDATABASE"
    );
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setUsers(res))
      .catch(err => setErrors(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return Users;
};
export { FetchUsers };
```

consumed here....

```
class UsersManager {
  constructor() {
    this.mapUserCountries = {};
  }
  init() {
    const mappedUsers = FetchUsers();
    mappedUsers.forEach(user => {
      const c = user.country;

      if (!this.mapUserCountries[c])
        this.mapUserCountries[c] = { nbUsers: 0, users: [] };
      this.mapUserCountries[c].nbUsers++;
      this.mapUserCountries[c].users.push(user);
    });
  }

  getUsersPerCountry(country) {
    return this.mapUserCountries[country];
  }
}

export default new UsersManager();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the FetchUsers inside a Class component, and the FetchUsers is executing a React Hook. This is not allowed by React.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that it couldn't be called in a class component, only used. I'm refactoring my class component as I don't think hooks is necessary for me in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

First - Hooks don't work inside class based components.

Second - All custom hooks should start with use, in your case useFetchUsers. By setting use as prefix, react will track your hook for deps and calling in correct order and so on.

Comment: It is not true that you must the word 'use' as a prefix, you should, but is not a must, react will track it, whether it starts with 'use' or not

Comment: For applying lint rules, which is very recommended, you must